# The provided DependencyObject is not a context for this Freezable WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to fill a `Reactangle`with an image from `OpenFileDialog`.

**XAML**

```
<Rectangle RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15">
<Rectangle.Fill>
      <ImageBrush x:Name="userpic" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" ImageSource="/icons/usericon.png"/>
</Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

**C#**

```
private void LoadImg() {
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ofpd = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    ofpd.Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.PNG;*.JPEG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.PNG;*.JPEG";
    ofpd.Title = "Add a photo";
    if ((ofpd.ShowDialog == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)) {
        userpic.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofpd.FileName));
    }

}
```

But it's throwing an error : `The provided DependencyObject is not a context for this Freezable.`..Any idea on why this is happening ?

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865002/what-is-a-parent-freezable-what-does-this-error-mean) but maybe i cant apply the solution as i am not creating the `ImageBrush` from code-Behind...??

Comment: Why don't you use an Image control?

Comment: As u can see, i am setting rectangle's radius to make it look like a circle...so,if i go with an image ,then i need to do some workarounds to get the round corners....But can u tell me why this error is occuring ?

Comment: *As u can see* where exactly?

Comment: i am so sorry, i just added it

Comment: Just a suggestion: You can do the same with an Ellipse to make it a circle probably better than a rectangle; unless you're only wanting curved edges.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII.good point man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a Name to the Rectangle

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15"/>
```

Then create a new ImageBrush and assign it to the Rectangle's Fill property:

```
var fill = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofpd.FileName)));
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(fill, BitmapScalingMode.Fant);
rect.Fill = fill;
```

Comment: Yes,it works...Can u tell me what was the problem ? What was causing this ?

Comment: Not sure, but the ImageBrush declared in XAML may be frozen after creation, so that you could not assign a new value to its ImageSource property. You could inspect the exception's call stack.