# Set BitmapImage dynamically via Binding using a converter in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, workflow-foundation-4

I have the following `xaml` (Note this is used in a Microsoft Workflow Foundation activity and is contained within a `<sap:ActivityDesigner.Icon>`. Hopefully, it won't matter but I thought I'd mention it.)

```
<DrawingBrush>
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <ImageDrawing>
            <ImageDrawing.Rect>
                <Rect Location="0,0" Size="16,16" ></Rect>
            </ImageDrawing.Rect>
            <ImageDrawing.ImageSource>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="MyImage.png"/>
            </ImageDrawing.ImageSource>
        </ImageDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

I need to change the UriSource at run-time so I thought I'd use a converter as such:

```
<DrawingBrush>
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <ImageDrawing>
            <ImageDrawing.Rect>
                <Rect Location="0,0" Size="16,16" ></Rect>
            </ImageDrawing.Rect>
            <ImageDrawing.ImageSource>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=MyObject, Converter={StaticResource NameToImageConverter}}"/>
            </ImageDrawing.ImageSource>
        </ImageDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

but if try to bind it to my object and use a converter, I'm getting the following error:

**The provided DependencyObject is not a context for this Freezable**

Note that it doesn't hit my converter.

I found [The provided DependencyObject is not a context for this Freezable WPF c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200779/the-provided-dependencyobject-is-not-a-context-for-this-freezable-wpf-c-sharp) which I thought would help but to no avail.

When setting a name to the BitmapImage object

```
<BitmapImage Name="MyBitmapImage"/>
```

I thought I'd be able to set this via code but I still get the same error.

I don't know what I've done since originally looking at this but originally I got an error saying something along the lines that I should use a beginInit and endInit. Sorry don't have the exact error since I can't replicate it.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: How about `<ImageDrawing ImageSource="{Binding ...}"/>` with a converter that returns an ImageSource instead of an Uri?

Comment: In case your MyObject is supposed to change its value during runtime and notify the UI, your approach won't work anyway, because a BitmapImage can only once be initialized by its UriSource property. It can't be changed later.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks a lot for suggestion! Can you stick that as an answer. It worked nicely setting the ImageSource on the ImageDrawing.I had to do a little bit more digging on how to load the image but it is working nicely with a converter now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BitmapImage implements the `ISupportInitialize` interface and can only be initialized once, and not changed later. If your `MyObject` is supposed to change its value during runtime and notify the UI, that won't work.

You can change the Binding to

```
<ImageDrawing
    ImageSource="{Path=MyObject, Converter={StaticResource NameToImageConverter}}"
    Rect="0,0,16,16" />
```

and make the Binding Converter return a BitmapImage instead of an Uri:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    ...
    string uri = ...;
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri));
}
```